# I cant remove the invisble space next to "Contact Me"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the space on top right on corner next to "Contact Me" And I can't figure out why it's there. I tried pushing it there but it still doesn't work. I'm still new and trying to learn.

[image]

Code:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


section {
    background-color: gray;
}

.hero {
    background-color: #1c1d25;
    height: 100vh;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
}



nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 500px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: 20px;
}


li {
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 90px;
    margin: 0;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
}


.logo {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 30px;
}


.home {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.myw {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.cm {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


.logo2{
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    border: 5px dotted purple;
}


p {
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
     position: absolute;
     left: 40vw;
     bottom: 40vh;
    width:50%;
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/aboutMeStyle.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>About Me</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="hero">
        <nav>
            <img class="logo" src="images/pack.png" alt="Futsunohitos Logo">
            <img class="logo2" src="images/32x_ava.png" alt="Futsunohitos Logo">
            <div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/tttei/OneDrive/Desktop/website/index.html" class="home"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/tttei/OneDrive/Desktop/website/index.html" class="myw"> My Work </a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/tttei/OneDrive/Desktop/website/index.html" class="cm"> Contact Me </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class= "glow">
            <p class="Description">Hello Im Oleg. Im 18 years old. I like to draw and make cool art. I take orders and can make you a custom avatar or anything you ask for. Ofcourse its gonna be really cheap I just want to start my own little business. I hope you enjoy my art (and maybe hire me). Have a great day!</p>
            </div>
        </nav>
            <script>
                "src/app.js"
            </script>
        
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add also the HTML code and not only CSS

Answer (score 0):

You have `justify-content: space-around;` on flex `ul` that gives some space around the flex items.

`justify-content: space-between` might be something you are looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: I tired changing it to what you recomended but it sadly didnt work. It almost seems like that the text under it has like a invisible line that doesnt let it go past it.